# eval and Binding in ruby

Tags: ruby, binding

I want to access the variable and method defined in top level main object in the program

```
@x = :hello

def instanceMethodMain
p  "instanceMethodMain"  
end

class Baz
  def method
     p eval("@x", TOPLEVEL_BINDING)
     p eval("instanceMethodMain", TOPLEVEL_BINDING)
  end  
end

Baz.new.method
```

the output is

```
:hello
"instanceMethodMain"
"instanceMethodMain"
```

The output is the same even if I use

```
mainRef=TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval('self')
p mainRef.send :instanceMethodMain
```

Could someone explain why instanceMethodMain is invoked twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instanceMethodMain` isn't called twice.

You can check it by adding

```
def instanceMethodMain
  puts "BEEN HERE"
  p  "instanceMethodMain"  
end
```

`p` is called twice with `"instanceMethodMain"` as parameter.

```
p p "instanceMethodMain"
#=> "instanceMethodMain"
#=> "instanceMethodMain"
```

Note that `p "string"` displays `"string"` **and** returns `"string"`, while `puts "string"` displays `string` and returns `nil` :

```
puts puts "instanceMethodMain"
#=> instanceMethodMain
#=>
```

Answer (score 2):

`"instanceMethodMain"` is printed twice because of double `p`.

```
p eval("instanceMethodMain", TOPLEVEL_BINDING)
```

is translated into

```
p p "instanceMethodMain"
#=> "instanceMethodMain"
#=> "instanceMethodMain"
```

Removing either one would print the `"instanceMethodMain"` only once:

```
def instanceMethodMain
  "instanceMethodMain"  
end


Baz.new.method
#=> :hello
#=> "instanceMethodMain"
```